# Comparative select on the same table (mysql)

Tags: mysql, select, statements

I'm really newbie with mysql and i'm tryin to do a simple select, but I can't figure it out.

Thats what I have:

```
I got this in a Table named Control:
| CODE | OFFICE |
|  1   |   usa  |
|  2   |   usa  |
|  3   |   usa  |
|  4   |   usa  |
|  5   |   usa  |
|  1   | china  |
|  3   | china  |
|  4   | china  |

And I need get this:

| CODE | OFFICE |
|  2   |   usa  |
|  5   |   usa  |
```

Then, SELECT code,office WHERE the codes still aren't registered with office = china.

I have to make a self join or something like that or use GROUP BY statement ?
I'm stuck here... I really would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is working

```
 create table Test(id integer, code integer, office varchar(100));

insert into Test(id, code, office) values(1, 1, "usa"),(2, 2, "usa"),(3, 3, "usa"),(4, 4, "usa"),(5, 5, "usa"),(6, 1, "china"),(7, 3, "china"),(8, 4, "china");

select * from Test;

Select * from Test where code NOT IN (select code from Test where office =   "china");
```

You have use sub query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a "Self-Left-Join" on `Code`, and consider only those rows where no match was found in the Right side, *i.e.*, right side value `IS NULL`

```
SELECT 
  tleft.*
FROM Control AS tleft
LEFT JOIN Control AS tright
  ON tright.Code = tleft.Code AND 
     tright.Office = 'china' 
WHERE tleft.Office = 'usa' AND 
      tright.Code IS NULL -- this filters no matching code found in china
```